# Generating random sample from multivariate normal distribution using Scala?

Tags: scala, math, statistics

Is there a package that lets you do this without having to generate individual samples from N(0,1)? Assume the covariance matrix isn't the identity matrix (i.e. the x_i's are correlated).

Comment: Have you tried Breeze?

Comment: I haven't - thanks!

Comment: Do you know if it has a CDF method? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I'd use import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution